# Not able to delete failed Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

in my Azure DevTest Lab, I've created 2 VMs. But, during the provisioning both are failed now and I cannot delete them.

I've delete the resource groups attached to these VMS, but they are still showing in my lab.

I think the issue was I maxed on the public IP so they failed.

I can only change them to unclaim, but still I cannot delete these two VMs.

Can you please let me how i can delete these VM, without deleting my DevTest lab?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've actually just found the answer by going to the my Devtest Lab resource group, there i could still see 2 VMs are still there > simply delete them from there.

Comment: I experienced a similar issue but in my case it was related to vCPU quota limits (regional + type). Doing what you proposed did allowed me to deleted these failed provisioned VMs.